# Add rangeSelector in bar graph in highcharts in SWIFT UI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, highcharts

How to make bar graphs in swift ui zoomable. I saw rangeSelector option available in js option but in swift ui there is no working example.

These are the examples : http://jsfiddle.net/D58fP/.
The references of API classes for IOS are here : https://api.highcharts.com/ios/highcharts/

```
$(function() {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        
        plotOptions: {
        },
        
        rangeSelector: {
            enabled: true
        },
        
        series: [{
            data: usdeur
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `chart.zooming` option, where you can set `"x", "y", "xy"` type zoom.

**Demo JS:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o3gtwzua/

**API Reference: HIZooming**
https://api.highcharts.com/ios/highcharts/

Comment: So rangeSelector API is not there in IOS version of highcharts. If I want to add buttons like 3months , 6months ago and zoom accordingly, how would I do it?

Comment: Hi, `rangeSelector` is available for Highcharts Stock only, which is currently not supported by iOS wrapper (https://www.highcharts.com/integrations/) . You can build a similar functionality using `xAxis.setExtremes` method - JS Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/axis-setextremes/ ; API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/ios/highcharts/Classes/HIXAxis.html#//api/name/setExtremes: